# Querying a custom type with Database.SqlQuery<T> in EF Core 7.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

The recently released Entity Framework Core 7.0 offers [a new `DatabaseFacade.SqlQuery<T>` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types), which allows to run custom SQL queries directly on the underlying database context.

For custom SQL queries, I am currently using [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper), which I would like to replace by EF's new native `SqlQuery` function. The respective queries cannot be easily expressed as LINQ, which EF could translate to SQL itself. Also, they return result objects that are not part of the database model.

As an illustrating example, take these simple classes and SQL query:

```cs
public class Book   // Mapped to database table 'books'
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; } // References some complex Author object

    // ...lots of other properties...
}

// Simple type for search results
public class BookSearchResult
{
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
}

// Search for books which satisfy a complex query
var books = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().QueryAsync<BookSearchResult>(@"
    SELECT a.`Name` AS 'AuthorName', b.`Title` AS 'BookTitle'
    FROM `books` b
    JOIN `authors` a ON a.Id = b.AuthorId
    ...complex query...
");
```

I would like to replace this by

```cs
var books = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<BookSearchResult>(@"
    ...same query...
");
```

---

Now, the [documentation of `SqlQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.sqlquery?view=efcore-7.0) also states the following (bold formatting added by me):

> Creates a LINQ query based on a raw SQL query, which returns a result set of a **scalar** type natively supported by the database provider.

I.e., it can/should only be used to query scalar types, but not custom objects.

There is a hint in the remarks that one can define a new default type mapping, but I don't really understand how this can be achieved in practice (or whether it is even possible).

Can I map the result of a `DbConnection.Database.SqlQuery<T>` call to a custom object? If so, how?

Comment: Nope, `SqlQuery` is only for fetching individual values, eg a single `DbDataReader.Get[type]()`, not for materialising entire classes.

Comment: Though there is a way to define a `DbContext` per result type https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1862#issuecomment-451671168.

Comment: Since `.SqlQuery<>` returns an `IQueryable<>`, provided you can simplify your complex sql to return a single column (eg a PK), you should be able to compose that query with a join to your model entity types and a projection to a custom type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently (EF Core 7) you can't.

This is a long time asked feature, eventually coming with EF Core 8 [SQL queries for unmapped types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/plan#sql-queries-for-unmapped-types):

> Tracked by [Issue #10753: Support raw SQL queries without defining an entity type for the result](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10753)
>
> Value proposition: Applications can execute more types of SQL query without dropping down to ADO.NET or using third-party libraries.
>
> Currently SQL queries must return a type in the model or a scalar type. In EF8, we plan to allow SQL queries that directly return types that are not contained in the EF model.